# Leaflet - popups for polygons over each other

Tags: leaflet, popup, polygon

I place polygons in front of a map. Some smaller polygons are placed in front of a bigger polygon. I get the data  from geojson file. I want to show the name-poperty as a popup. I use:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.name);
```

};

Unfortunately only the name-property of the bigger ploygon is shown. How can i correct this? I tried an additionl geojson-property with:

```
        function onEachFeature(feature, layer) { 
    if ((feature.properties.popupContent != "0"))
        {layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.name);
        };
```

};

But this does not work too.

thanks, wonk

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet provides a couple of functions to help access smaller markers that may be trapped under larger markers, those being the [`.bringToFront()` and `.bringToBack()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-bringtofront) methods provided by `L.Path`, `L.featureGroup`, and `L.GridLayer` and inherited by any descendants of those. I've set up a live, rudimentary example of using these to access trapped markers on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1d6hu1?file=index.js).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the example, I understand. I tried:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) { 
 if ((feature.properties.popupContent != "0"))
        {layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.name);
         layer.bringToFront();
        };
 }
```

But this only shows the first polygon (there are a lot of them). Maybe, I misunderstood the geojson-data. I thought, there is one layer for every polygon. But it seems, that all polygons of geojson-data-file are in ONE layer. In this case your proposal won't work, I think. I will have to find another solution. The data come from:

```
    function show_geojson (overlay) {
    $.ajax({url:overlay}).done(function(data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
       L.geoJson(data, 
            {pointToLayer: MarkerStyle,
            style: style,
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            });
    geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data); //neu
    });
}
```

Thank you!